# How can I remove unwanted civilizations in civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

There are a lot of civilizations I don't consider 'real civs' in the game. I won't list them to avoid debate =). The thing is, I want to avoid them spawning in my games, yet I still want the civs list to be random.
How can I achieve that? Is there a mod for this? I think I saw one at one point, but cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Nuclear weapons are always good, I find ;-) [you didn't say 'from the configuration']

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Really Advanced Setup](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=126959669&searchtext=really%20advanced%20setup)** is the mod you are looking for.If you own the game on steam you can download it with mentioned link.
Otherwise download [this](http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=20830)

Along all the other awesome features for setting up your game this mod will give you an option to choose the **active civilizations** that can appear in the game...so you can disable those pesky Mongols once and for all xD.

> "Select Active Civilizations:  This allows you to determine which
>   civilizations are active. Deactivate the civs that you don't want and
>   they won't show up. Even when using randomly selected civilizations. "

[image]

Comment: Note that there really isn't mod support on Macs. :(